# Como funciona el operador not in en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, operador

Tengo un array let a con elementos. Otro array let b vacio. Quiero pasar los elementos de array a a array b, siempre y cuando ese elemento no este en el array b. Asi evito duplicados. Utilizaria lo que en python en not in. Porque agregar dos veces el 1? solo deberia agregar el primero.

```
let a=[1,1,2,3,1]
let b=[]

for (let i=0;i<a.length;i++){
  if(!(a[i]in b)){
    b.push(a[i])
  }

}
  console.log(b)
```

Comment: Nota que `let` es un keyword de javascript que se usa con variables al igual que `var`. El primero se usa para declarar o definir variables de ámbito local mientras que el segundo globales.

Comment: entiendo. el problema que al imprimir el codigo quedaria.
b=[1,1,2,3] yo quiero que quede [1,2,3] ya que el 1 es repetido, no deberia agregarse. porque se agrega?

Answer (score 2):

```js
let a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1]
let b = []


//Debería ser asi: 
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (!b.includes(a[i])) {
    
    b.push(a[i])
  }

}
console.log(b)
```

## [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

> El operador in devuelve true si la propiedad especificada está en el objeto especificado o su prototipo.

Básicamente estas buscando una propiedad:

> Los siguientes ejemplos muestran algunos de los usos del operador in.

```
// Arrays
var arboles = new Array("secoya", "pino", "cedro", "roble", "arce");
0 in arboles        // devuelve true
3 in arboles        // devuelve true
6 in arboles        // devuelve false
"pino" in arboles   // devuelve false (debe especificar el número de índice,
                    // no el valor del índice)
"length" in arboles // devuelve true (length es una propiedad de Array)

// Objetos predefinidos
"PI" in Math        // devuelve true

// Objetos personalizados
var micoche = {marca: "Honda", modelo: "Accord", año: 1998};
"marca" in micoche  // devuelve true
"modelo" in micoche // devuelve true
```

Puedes crear un [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) y este se encargara de limpiar los duplicados, despues lo conviertes en arreglo para tener operaciones como push, pop, etc.

```js
let a=[1,1,2,3,1]
let b= Array.from(new Set(a))

console.log(b)
```

Comment: gracias, pero entonces el operador not in no funciona como tal? lo que busco es que agregue al elemento a la otra lista si es que ya no esta en la lista. y falla. algo debe estar mal en mi codigo.

Comment: Hago un ejemplo para mostrarte.

Comment: @Nam Edite mi respuesta.

Comment: Gracias, lo mas cercano seria el includes()

Answer (score 1):

El operador `in` en Javascript no funciona como crees.

Devuelve `true` si el objeto tiene la **propiedad** indicada.

En el caso de un `arreglo = [8, 4, 1]`:

- `8 in arreglo` y `4 in arreglo` darán falso porque no tiene elementos en las posiciones 8 y 4.
- 0, 1 y 2 darán verdadero porque sí hay elementos en esas posiciones.

Para saber si hay un **elemento** en el arreglo, puedes usar la función `indexOf`. Que devuelve la posición de la primera ocurrencia de un valor. Si no encuentra ninguna, devuelve -1. Así:

```
let arreglo = [3, 10, 7]
arreglo.indexOf(7) // Devuelve 2
arreglo.indexOf(20) // Devuelve -1
```

Comment: ok, gracias, estime funcionaba como en python el in y not in.

Answer (score 1):

Tu codigo no funciona porque estas usando el operador `in` que se usa mas para saber si una propiedad existe en un objeto.

En este caso como es un array el operador `in` estaria validando si el `index` existe y no el valor como tal. Entonces, en la primera iteracion valida si `1` existe en el arreglo `b`, como `b` esta vacio entonces no existe el index 1 (es false) entonces hace el primer push al arreglo `b`. El la segunda iteracion pasa lo mismo.

Lo que podrias usar es el metodo `.includes()`. Este verifica que el valor exista en el arreglo.

Tu codigo quedaria asi:

```javascript
let a=[1,1,2,3,1]
let b=[]

for (let i=0;i<a.length;i++){
  if(!b.includes(a[i])){
    b.push(a[i])
  }

}
  console.log(b)
```

Pero me gusta mas lo que sugiere @Legna de usar `Set` para remover los duplicados.